# Lazy Initialization Exception on Initialize a Collection - JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, primefaces

I implement a simple SpringMVC application. As models I have `Person` and `Event` both get mapped to a `H2 database`.

For now I am able to store a `Person` object and an `Event` object as well. But when I am trying to store a list of `Person` to my `Event` object than I always get the exception:

> failed to lazily initialize a collection, could not initialize proxy - no Session

My approach so far:

```
@Entity
public class Event implements Persistable<Long> {

      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
      private Long id;

      private String eventName;

      @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
      @ElementCollection(targetClass = Member.class)
      private List<Person> members = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
public class Person implements Persistable<Long>{

      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
      private Long id;

      private String firstname;
      private String lastname;
}
```

The goal is to select `Person` objects with a primefaces `SelectManyMenu` and store them to the `List<Person> members` of the event. When I add some `Person` objects to an `Event` via `SQL` than the `SelectManyMenu` pre-selects the added `Person` objects correctly. But when I select an additional `Person` object and call `save` then the exception appears.

First I thought my `save`-method doesn't work. But it has to work correctly because I am able to save `Person` objects and `Event` objects separately (without a `Relationship` between).

Answer (score 0):

To map properly, you should map `members` field as `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "event", fetch = ...)`, and add `@ManyToOne Event event` in your `Person` class. Also you can be certain about what fetching strategy needed to use by reading [fetching strategies](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching) document.

Comment: that would mean that a Person can only take part to one event? .. a Person should be allowed to take part to many events

Comment: If an _event should be allowed to take part to many persons_ also, you should use `@ManyToMany` mapping for both.

Comment: I tried `@ManyToMany` mapping for both. `@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)` annotation for my `Person` set in `Event` and `@ManyToMany(mappedBy="members", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)` annotation for my `Event` set in `Person` but still no success. Do I something wrong?